# localization for Right to Left language in windows store application ( 8 Mero )

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-store-apps

at first I must mention, I search a lot but there is no solution for windows 8 metro style application. I design an application which should be support Persian language in Windows RT. Strings are ok but the problem is how to change the direction of UI elements.
please advice me.

Answer (score 0):

[How to adjust layout and fonts for various languages, and support RTL layouts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh967760%28v=win.10%29.aspx)